# How do I sort an array according to an input?

Tags: python

My program prioritizes lowercase letters first then uppercase then digits but in the end I want it to be sorted the same way as the user input.

```
import time

userInput = input('Enter some random thing here: ')
lowerCaseLetters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
upperCaseLetters = lowerCaseLetters.upper()
digits = '123456789'
ret = []

finishedLowerCaseCycle = False
finishedUpperCaseCycle = False

for i in password:
    for j in lowerCaseLetters:
        if j == i:
            ret.append(j)
            finishedLowerCaseCycle = True

if finishedLowerCaseCycle == True:
    for i in password:
        for j in upperCaseLetters:
            if j == i:
                ret.append(j)
                finishedUpperCaseCycle = True

if finishedUpperCaseCycle == True:
    for i in password:
        for j in digits:
            if j == i:
                ret.append(j)


print(ret)
```

userInput = 'Python123'

Output = ['y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'P', '1', '2' , '3']

Expected Output = ['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', '1', '2', '3']

Comment: what is ```password```

Comment: Why don't you just take out each characters: `[c for c in 'Python123']`

Comment: I agree with @Don'tAccept, Why to go through this instead of ```[char for char in userInput]```

Comment: Why even bother with the comprehension: `list("Python123")` works, but I suspect the OP is going for something else...maybe.

Comment: @Mark, yeah I also believe so, it's just that OP was probably not able to provide a better example.

Comment: Your password variable is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying to do this:

```
import string

user_input = input('Enter a proposed password:')
password = ''.join(
    ch for ch in user_input 
    if ch in string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
)
print(password)
```